# Flink windows do not fire after connecting to broadcast stream

Tags: apache-flink

I try to use BroadcastStatePattern to extend the functionality of my application.
Some code here. `Main`

```
// .... ///
val gatewayBroadcastStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor[String, BCA]("gatewayEvents", classOf[String], classOf[BCASTDATACLASS])


// Broadcast source
val broadcastSource = env
  .addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer[String](s"BROADCAST", new SimpleStringSchema, consumerConfig))

val broadcastSourceGatewayEvents = broadcastSource
  .filter(_.contains("someText"))
  .map(json => read[BCASTDATACLASS](json))

val broadcastGatewayEventsConfigurations = broadcastSourceGatewayEvents.broadcast(gatewayBroadcastStateDescriptor)

// packet source
val packetSource = env
  .addSource(
    new FlinkKinesisConsumer[String](s"PACKETS", new SimpleStringSchema, consumerConfig))

val packets = packetSource.disableChaining()
  .map(json => read[MAINDATACLASS](json))
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy
    .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[MAINDATACLASS](Duration.ofSeconds(2))
    .withTimestampAssigner(new PacketWatermarkGenerator))
  .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(2))
  .process(new OrderPacketWindowFunction)
  .disableChaining()

// connect MainDataSource with BroadcastDataSource
val gwEnrichedPackets = packets
  .keyBy(_.gatewayId)
  .connect(broadcastGatewayEventsConfigurations)
  .process(new EnrichingPackets)
```

My `window` function (in this example doing nothing, just forward data further )

```
//....//

class EnrichingPackets()
  extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction[String, MAINDATACLASS, BCASTDATACLASS, MAINDATACLASS]
    with LazyLogging {

  private lazy val gatewayEventsStateDescriptor =
    new MapStateDescriptor[String, BCASTDATACLASS]("gatewayEvents", classOf[String], classOf[BCASTDATACLASS])

override def processBroadcastElement( // stream element, context, collector to emit resulting elements
                                    broadcastInput: BCASTDATACLASS,
                                    ctx: KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction[String, MAINDATACLASS, BCASTDATACLASS, MAINDATACLASS]#Context,
                                    out: Collector[MAINDATACLASS]): Unit = {

val gatewayEvents = ctx.getBroadcastState(gatewayEventsStateDescriptor)
println("OK")

}

  override def processElement(
                           packetInput: MAINDATACLASS,
                           readOnlyCtx: KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction[String, MAINDATACLASS, GatewayEvent, MAINDATACLASS]#ReadOnlyContext,
                           out: Collector[MAINDATACLASS]): Unit = {

// get read-only broadcast state
val gatewayEvents = readOnlyCtx.getBroadcastState(gatewayEventsStateDescriptor)
out.collect(packetInput)
  }
}
```

After connecting data and configuration streams im going to open window and do some processing.
But when i open window from `gwEnrichedPackets` nothing happened, i can see (flink ui) ONLY incoming messages into window. Even using `session windows` and stop the data flow - windows do not fire.

`allowedLateness` and `sideOutputLateData` do not help the investigation of the problem

An interesting point is that if I open windows from `packets` - everything works properly.

```
//  val sessionWindows = gwEnrichedPackets - NOT works
//  val sessionWindows = packets - Works

val sessionWindows = gwEnrichedPackets
  .keyBy(_.tag.tagId)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(20))
  //.window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(120)))
  //.allowedLateness(Time.seconds(12000))
  //.sideOutputLateData(new OutputTag[MAINDATACLASS]("late-readings"))
  .process(new DetectTagGatewayDisconnections)

val lateStream = sessionWindows
  .getSideOutput(new OutputTag[MAINDATACLASS]("late-readings"))

lateStream.print()
sessionWindows.print()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is watermarking in this case, You are assigning Watermarks only to one of the streams, Flink always picks the lowest Watermark when more than one stream is on the input of the given operator.

So, in Your case Flink has to pick between Watermark generated by `packets` and the one generated by broadcast stream and one of them will be always `Long.MinVal` (because the control stream has no watermark generator), so it will always pick `Long.MinVal` and thus windows will never progress.

In this case, You can simply add Watermark assigner to the `gwEnrichedPackets` stream and that should solve the issue.